# One aiohttp ClientSession per thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In the [documentation for `aiohttp.ClientSession`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html) I have read that you should, ideally, create one `ClientSession` per application. I suspect that that should read something like "create one ClientSession per thread" (I'm in python 3x).

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_it_async(url: str, session):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        print(resp.status)
        print(len(await resp.text()))

def run_it(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    # New thread - get the loop.
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    assert not loop.is_running()
    return loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_task(fn(*args, **kwargs)))

        
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)

client = aiohttp.ClientSession()
await asyncio.wrap_future(pool.submit(run_it, get_it_async, 'httyp://nytimes.com', client))
```

Gives me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-180a408a9698> in async-def-wrapper()

~\appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py in run(self)
     55 
     56         try:
---> 57             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     58         except BaseException as exc:
     59             self.future.set_exception(exc)

<ipython-input-1-180a408a9698> in run_it(fn, *args, **kwargs)
     15 
     16 
---> 17 from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
     18 pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)
     19 

~\appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py in run_until_complete(self, future)
    585             raise RuntimeError('Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
    586 
--> 587         return future.result()
    588 
    589     def stop(self):

<ipython-input-1-180a408a9698> in get_it_async(url, session)
      6         print(resp.status)
      7         print(len(await resp.text()))
----> 8 
      9 def run_it(fn, *args, **kwargs):
     10     # New thread - get the loop.

i:\gwatts\code\calratio2019\calms\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py in __aenter__(self)
   1010 
   1011     async def __aenter__(self) -> _RetType:
-> 1012         self._resp = await self._coro
   1013         return self._resp
   1014 

i:\gwatts\code\calratio2019\calms\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py in _request(self, method, str_or_url, params, data, json, cookies, headers, skip_auto_headers, auth, allow_redirects, max_redirects, compress, chunked, expect100, raise_for_status, read_until_eof, proxy, proxy_auth, timeout, verify_ssl, fingerprint, ssl_context, ssl, proxy_headers, trace_request_ctx)
    424         timer = tm.timer()
    425         try:
--> 426             with timer:
    427                 while True:
    428                     url, auth_from_url = strip_auth_from_url(url)

i:\gwatts\code\calratio2019\calms\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py in __enter__(self)
    577 
    578         if task is None:
--> 579             raise RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used '
    580                                'inside a task')
    581 

RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Is there a bug in my code, or is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2):

As I know, `ClientSession()` and all nested objects save loop object (e.g. `self._loop`) while instantiated. And when you try to use it in another thread (and therefore another active event loop), `ClientSession` internal code cannot find current task for own saved loop and raises this exception.

I think for every new thread (and for every new loop) new `ClientSession` should be instantiated.

Comment: I think this is correct. I was looking through the source code, and the only thing that gave me pause was saying that "loop" and providing it was depreciated - I couldn't tell if that was going to make this work with other loops, or if it was just going to internalize the dependency.

Answer (score 2):

> I suspect that that should read something like "create one ClientSession per thread" (I'm in python 3x).

That interpretation is incorrect for several reasons. First, the recommendation is meant exactly as written - one `ClientSession` is typically used per application, where an application is a program that performs a number of independent (but loosely related) downloads. For example, a web crawler would be an application, and so would be a bittorrent client, etc. Multiple applications can run inside a single process, in which case it makes sense to create multiple sessions which are completely independent from each other.

The second problem is that asyncio is single-threaded, so it doesn't make sense to speak of "one session *per thread*". One of the selling points of asyncio is that you can achieve scalable parallelism that *doesn't* depend on creating a huge number of OS threads. Your code that creates a thread to run a whole new event just to download something is technically correct, but unnecessary, especially since your top-level code appears to be running inside asyncio to begin with! It's also potentially complex and error-prone because if you ever want to share data between downloads, you will need to deal with inter-thread synchronization issues.

The way to achieve parallelism in asyncio is to use a *single* event loop in your process, and do everything inside it. For example, taking your `get_it_async` function as a starting point, you might do this to download three URLs in parallel:

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(
            get_it_async('https://nytimes.com', session),
            get_it_async('https://yahoo.com', session),
            get_it_async('https://cnn.com', session),
        )

# or, await main() if you call main from another async function
asyncio.run(main())
```

Functions like `asyncio.wrap_future` (and more typically its cousin `loop.run_in_executor`) should only be used when invoking CPU-bound or legacy blocking code from within an asyncio application. If you have async code and invoke it from async, just await it or use `asyncio.gather()` and similar to make it run in parallel.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment in this answer. I would be single-threaded if I could be. Unfortunately, because my code has to have both async and non-async entry points, and has to run in environments from the command line and also in a Jupiter notebook (which has its own async loop) - to support that matrix I either have to use the `nest_asyncio` package or be able to support different threads. I tried the package and got burned several times as it is patching python, so I moved over to multiple threads.

Comment: @Gordon Why do you need both async and non-async entry points? If you need non-async just for regular usage (outside Jupyter), then your non-async entry point could simply run `asyncio.run(main())`. Inside Jupyter you'd just use `await main()` since, as you point out, Jupyter already runs an event loop.